# How to retrieve Textbox value even after page is refreshed in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I have 2 Textbox and 3 select box which contains Date such as "EventId","State","Distrcit","schools","Event Date" and a submit button. I am calling the same page through servlet, when I hit the submit button. So after its reloaded, I want to show "EventId","State","Distrcit","schools","Event Date" the value that was selected before it was refreshed.

[image]

when i click "Save and Display Student Details" submit button, it goes to servlet and add into DB and come back to same(EventCreateJspPage.jsp) page.i want to create 100 student details for same Event details.thats what i want to hold previous datum.

How should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just sent the data back from the servlet and populate the elements accordingly...

Comment: or use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to submit you data

Comment: @TJ even i tried  <%
 if(request.getAttribute("HoldedText1Value")!=null && request.getAttribute("HoldedText2Value")!=null)
 {%>
  //get textbox and select box values from servlet 
 <% }%>

Comment: @Pete yes thats good idea but i want to do in MVC architech!

Comment: @Pete sorry could not get you.are you saying that jsp to jsp is MVC model? like jsp to servlet?

Comment: Fetch the data from db during page load and show it inside those fields. :)

Comment: @lllusion if i do this then shows error as Null pointer exception when open that page first time.

Comment: How you redirect back to JSP page from servlet ?

Comment: @JavaDev using response.sendRedirect("EventCreateJspPage.jsp");

Comment: Is your dropdown values are static or it is loaded dynamically on selection ?

Comment: @JavaDev not static.loaded dynamically from DB using ajax.